# How to use variables in a different class in a new class

Tags: java, class, oop, getter-setter

I recently learned about getters and setters for variables so I wanted to make use of it. I created a separate class for the variables which uses getters and setters. I would want to use the variables I made in this class in a different class that contains formulas. How do I use the variables in the Formulas class?

This is my variables class:

```
public class Variables {

    private int width, height, smallRectangle, bigRectangle;

    //getters
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getSmallRectangle() {
        return smallRectangle;
    }

    public int getBigRectangle() {
        return bigRectangle;
    }

    //setters

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public void setSmallRectangle(int smallRectangle) {
        this.smallRectangle = smallRectangle;
    }

    public void setBigRectangle(int bigRectangle) {
        this.bigRectangle = bigRectangle;
    }
```

and these are the formulas that should be in the formulas class (this does not work)

```
public class Formulas {
    
    public static int rectangleFormula(){
        smallRectangle=width*height;
        bigRectangle=smallRectangle*5
    }
```

**EDITED:**

```
public class Formulas {
    public static int rectangleFormula(Textview a, Textview b, Textview c, Textview d){
        Variables v= new Variables();
        int width = v.getWidth();
        int height = v.getHeight();
        int smallRectangle = width*height;
        int bigRectangle = smallRectangle*5;

        a.setText(Integer.toString(v.width()));
        b.setText(Integer.toString(v.height()));
        c.setText(Integer.toString(v.smallRectangle()));
        d.setText(Integer.toString(v.bigRectangle()));
        
    }
```

Comment: You should read about how to create instances of a class.

Comment: Firstly create the instance of the Variables class then using setters set the width and height then you can use getters to access these variables' values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use the class `Variables` as a shared repository of constant, you will need to declare all the fields/methods as `static` (class properties). Otherwise, you'll have to create an instance of that class `Variables v = new Variables()` first. Only then can you use `v.getWidth()` and `v.setWidth()`.

```
public class Formulas {
    
    public static int rectangleFormula(Variables v){
        int width = v.getWidth();
        int height = v.getHeight();
        int smallRectangle = width*height;
        int bigRectangle = smallRectangle*5;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I have edited my question and wanted to know if what I did is correct? I am still having trouble with how to pass inputted width and height to a different activity and so I am unable to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getters and setters like this.

```
public class Formulas {

public static int rectangleFormula(){
    
    Variables v = new Variables();
    v.setWidth(5);
    v.setHeight(10);
    int smallRectangle=v.getWidth() * v.getHeight();
    int bigRectangle=smallRectangle*5;
    System.out.println("smallRectangle: " + smallRectangle + 
                       "\nbigRectangle:" + bigRectangle);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for this! I have edited my question and wanted to know if what I did is correct? I am still having trouble with how to pass inputted width and height to a different activity and so I am unable to see if it works.

Comment: I just saw your edited question, before using getters you must need to use setters to set the values use like this =>  v.setWidth(5); v.setHeight(10);

Comment: If you want to get the value from input then please use EditText instead of Textview like this => edit.getText().toString() and then cast it to an integer then pass to the setter.

Comment: But width and height should be inputted by the user in the first activity... Shouldn't I not use setters for it?

Comment: Yes for user input see my second comment, Thanks